# How to share session variables between .net core and .net framework 4.0

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, session, redis, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a legacy .net framework mvc 4.0 application with authentication, that will have a new module. In the new module will be developed with .net core 2.2 mvc.

The requirement is to login in the legacy application and some links will redirect to the new site, because of login, I need to share some information about user.

I tried to save the session of .net framework y .net core in redis, but they save information in a different way.

How I can share the information?